# Installshield - The files for installation requirement could not be found. The installation will now stop

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I am using `InstallShield` to build an installer to install some custom prerequisites on my client computers. But everytime I try to run the installer, I get:

> The files for installation requirement Crystal Runtime x86 could not be found. The installation will now stop. This is probably due to a failed, or canceled download.

I have told the prereq where the File sits on my local development machine, and it seems like InstallSheild takes this file, and copies it to the ISSetupPrerequisites folder in the same directory as the .exe file it generates. I can confirm my file exists in the ISSetupPrerequisites folder.

Is there something else I need to do to tell the installer where my .msi installer is for my prerequisite?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you've copied the installer (setup.exe or something similar) to the PC that you're installing on but not the ISSetupPrerequisites folder. You need to do this because you haven't changed the setting that puts the prerequisites (Crystal Runtime x86 in your case) inside the installer itself.

To enable this, go to your release's "Setup.exe" tab and change the value of the property called "InstallShield Prerequisites Location" from "Copy From Source Media" to "Extract From Setup.exe".

Answer (score 1):

You should verify the checksum and filesize attributes in the redistributable's pre-requisite file. If these don't match the local/downloaded file you'll see that error

(Example files node for MSFT VS 2010 Tools for Office Runtime)

```xml
<files>
    <file LocalFile="&lt;ISProductFolder&gt;\SetupPrerequisites\VSTOR\vstor_redist.exe" URL="http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/5/1/B51D2F9E-1432-4B76-8248-F47316BB8EE0/vstor_redist.exe" CheckSum="a1b5c8fb246a9d0d66f12d3b6f5e471d" FileSize=" 0,40051808"></file>
</files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the CheckSum value inside the .prq file is exactly the same as the MD5 checksum of the package copies on the web url and under < ISProductFolder >\SetupPrerequisites

You can calculate MD5 on windows using the command
*certutil.exe -hashfile myPackage.exe MD5*